# How can I set image dimensions in mm

Tags: php, css

If i have an image with size in pixels 190x380. Now if I want to get this image as width 58mm and height 115mm and when i print it will be the same as width 58mm and height 115mm. So how can i do that?

Comment: Web browsers don't deal in physical dimensions. That's up to the user when he or she prints the image.

Comment: You can use `mm` as the unit in CSS, but it probably won't do what you think.

Comment: You nee to know the DPI (dots per inch)/PPI (pixels per inch) of the image/printed result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be able to get what your after by playing around with the DPI of your image (that is dots per inch). For how an image displays on screen, DPI is meaningless but when printed, it comes into play.

You can find a larger discussion about it here: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/02/the-myth-of-dpi/. Both the article and the comments are worth a read.

Comment: ppi actually, unless you print it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot not.

The screen/print resolution is a dynamic factor and depends on the brand and size. Mac used to have 72 DPI, Windows 96 DPI. Most old laserprinters are 300 DPI

So: if your image needs to be 58mm ( 2.7 inch) you get 72 x 2.7 = 194 pixels on a mac and 259 pixels on a windows machine. But you need 810 pixels on a old laserprinter.

But that where the old days, nowadays every device has its own specific resolution, so you will not be able to calculate the right size for every device out there.